# Choose function to load from an R package

Tags: r, function, namespaces, package, rename

I like using function `reshape` from the `matlab` package, but I need then to specify `base::sum(m)` each time I want to sum the elements of my matrix or else `matlab::sum` is called, which only sums by columns..

I need loading package `gtools` to use the `rdirichlet` function, but then the function `gtools::logit` masks the function `pracma::logit` that I like better..

I gess there are no such things like:

```
library(loadOnly = "rdirichlet", from = "gtools")
```

or

```
library(loadEverythingFrom = "matlab", except = "sum")
```

.. because functions from the package `matlab` may internaly work on the `matlab::sum` function. So the latter *must* be loaded. But is there no way to get this behavior from the point of view of the user? Something that would feel like:

```
library(pracma)
library(matlab)
library(gtools)
sum <- base::sum
logit <- pracma::logit
```

.. but that would not spoil your `ls()` with all these small utilitary functions?

Maybe I need defining my own default namespace?

Comment: For two packages with conflicting names, a package loaded at a higher position `library(..., pos = number)` would take priority. You can see the position of your packages with `search()`. If you were to load `pracma` at a lower position than `gtools` then your `logit` should be the one you want. I don't know how to resolve the `base::sum` issue. I think you are better off just using the `library::function` syntax for calling the function you want.

Comment: @Vlo Too bad. But thanks for the `pos` trick, this is gonna help a little.. :)

Comment: You can organize the search path with a `.Rprofile` file and/or an `.onLoad()` function at the top of your script

Comment: Plese note that package 'pracma' has a `Reshape` Function, with capital letter to avoid the clash with `stats::reshape`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid spoiling your `ls`, you can do something like this:

```
.ns <- new.env()
.ns$sum <- base::sum
.ns$logit <- pracma::logit
attach(.ns)
```

Comment: I can't tell whether this is a hack or not, but I kinda like it. ;) I'll try ordering my `search()` better first, then fall back on my knees with your trick.. only for the cases where I'm too lazy to use `::`.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no easy answer to what you want to achieve. The only dirty hack I can think of is to download the source of the packages "matlab", "gtools", "pracma" and delete the offending functions from their NAMESPACE file prior to installation from source (with R CMD INSTALL package).

However, I would recommend using the explicit notation pracma::logit, because it improves readability of your code for other people and yourself in the future.

This site gives a good overview about package namespaces:
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html

Comment: Yope, too much dirt for this hack, and not sharer-friendly. But thank you for this site, I've learned a lot!